# Copy & Paste over several files with vim?

Tags: vim

Vim seems nice for most of the times and outperforms other editors in some categories.  But what about Copy&Paste?  (It seems to me that even MS DOS' EDIT.COM seems to outperform vim in this category.)

Scenario 1: I have a software project, lots of directories and I want to move a function from one file to another.  What is the most efficient way to do that?

Scenario 2: I activate indentation.  It seems in conflict with multi-line copy&paste.  I remember seeing on the internet people suggesting to switch indentation off during this process.  At the same time I even saw some weird macros.  Is there an efficient solution?

Comment: Hahaha, edit.com > vim. Some nerds are going to be angry with you!

Comment: I like to be provocative :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. if you use `NERDTree` plugin directories are not your enemy and otherwise you can open multiple files in tabs or split the window.
2. copied text can be pasted from clipboard by `"+p` and within vim yankin(=copying) and pasting works flawless - not only multiple lines but also blockwise - i don't know if M$ DOS Edit can do that.

---

I don't know if any text-editor survives more than 20 years in the wilderness if it performs bad at copying or moving text between files.

Comment: NERDTree definitely makes working with vim more fun... I know 2 persons using vim (one of them convinced) and both use it really inefficently... Basically my fingers hurt when looking ;)

Comment: the fingers only hurt because the typing speed makes the keys burn ;)

Comment: I thought it was chronic illness from typing ;)

Answer (score 1):

`:open` the first file, yank, `:open` the second file, paste. You may want to [use a plugin such as NERDTree](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41395) to locate the second file faster.

To copy-paste between two different instances of Vim: yank in the first file, call `:wv` to write the [viminfo file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#viminfo-file); in the other file, call `:rv` to read the viminfo file then paste.

Indendation doesn't matter to Vim's copy-paste. It only matters when you paste data from the X clipboard into a text terminal, because Vim can't tell that this is pasted text and not something you typed. When pasting multiple lines from the X clipboard into a text terminal, first `:set paste` to turn off all automatic text processing (indentation, abbreviations, wrapping, …).

If you're running Vim under X or in an X terminal and your Vim supports it, you can copy and paste data through the X clipboard. Yank and paste to the `*` register for the X11 selection and to the `+` register for the X clipboard. For example, `"*42yy` in the first file and `"*p` in the second file.